# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the exceptional simple Lie group E6, E7, E8

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, cartan-geometry

What is the significance of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the exceptional simple Lie group root lattice to the Lie group or other mathematics branches?

For example,

- E6, we have
  $$
  \left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
   2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
  \end{array}
  \right)
  $$
  with eigenvalues:
  $${3.93185, 3., 2.51764, 1.48236, 1., 0.0681483}.$$
- E7, we have $$
  \left(
  \begin{array}{ccccccc}
   2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
  \end{array}
  \right)$$
  with eigenvalues:
  $$
  {3.96962, 3.28558, 2.68404, 2., 1.31596, 0.714425, 0.0303845}
  $$
- E8, we have
  $$
  \left(
  \begin{array}{cccccccc}
   2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
  \end{array}
  \right)
  $$
  with eigenvalues:
  $$
  {3.98904, 3.48629, 2.81347, 2.41582, 1.58418, 1.18653, 0.51371, 0.0109562}
  $$
  Of course we know eigenvalues can be used to built invariant such as determinant of the matrix. But here I ask the  significance of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the exceptional simple Lie group or other mathematics branches?
- For example E8 lattice can be used for the intersection form of E8 manifolds.

Comment: This may be related: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.6620.pdf

Comment: Name of @GA316's [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376639/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-of-the-exceptional-simple-lie-group-e6-e7-e8#comment955060_376639):  [Damianou - On the characteristic polynomial of Cartan matrices and Chebyshev polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6620). \\ Also, as a matter of terminology, you are taking eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a Cartan matrix, not of a root system or of a Lie group (whatever that would mean).